# ZendFramework - How to add ->HeadScript() from Controllers?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a case where i need to add the Javascript from controller to the Layout where it has already HeadScript();

How to do that from controller?

e.g: `$this->view->HeadScript()->appendScript();`

This is controller: Both does not apply.

```
class RouterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  public function init()
  {
    $this->view->HeadScript()->appendFile('/js/test.js')->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->HeadScript( Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript::FILE, '/js/test.js' );
  }
}
```

This is the view file: index.phtml

```
<?//$this->HeadScript()->appendFile('/js/test.js')->setIndent(8);?>
```

If i uncomment in view it works but not in Controller. I want to apply this from controller how now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work from the preDispatch method in a controller, remember you have to pass layout changes before headers are passed.

```
public function preDispatch() {
        parent::preDispatch();
        $layout = new Zend_Layout();

        $layout->getView()->headScript()->appendScript('/javascript/form.js', 'text/javascript');
    }
```

you still have to have the headScript placeholder in your layout.

Comment: But that preDispatch, which results to anything if i have 100 controllers? And i want random javascript i can not do this with this.

Comment: @Google you can put a preDispatch() in every controller if you like. In fact it's already there you just rarely ever see it. So for controller level changes to layouts and such it's great.

Comment: You are correct, this was my answer. I can no apply exactly how i wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/path/to/file.js');
```

Comment: If i do it manually in the .phtml file then it does but not when i do from controllers. e.g: `<?//$this->HeadScript()->appendFile('/js/namespace.extra.js')->setIndent(8);?>`

Comment: @Google Also watch letter casing. `HeadScript()` should be `headScript()`

Comment: Does not work from "*************CONTROLLERS*************". (works from VIEWS).

Comment: I use this method in my controllers all the time. Perhaps you are somehow meddling with $this->view elsewhere? I.e., maybe it's not set to what you think it is?

Comment: @Google Alex wrote `$this->view->headScript()` not `$this->headScript()`. The `view` property of `$this` while your in a controller refers to the view. Note that this is true for ZF1. I think ZF2 has decoupled the view from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?//$this->HeadScript()->appendFile('/js/test.js')->setIndent(8);//Your question ?>
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/path/to/file.js');//Alex Howansky's answer
```

There slightly different. :)

Comment: I am not trying to execute it from VIEWS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->view->HeadScript( Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript::FILE, '/path/to/file.js' );
```

or

```
$this->view->HeadScript( Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript::SCRIPT, 'js code' );
```

The same for `$this->view->InlineScript()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headScript = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headScript');
$headScript->prependFile($this->getSystemBaseUrl()."js/front_end/lib/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js","text/javascript");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case if its still useful to someone, you need to include following in layout script file:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```

Reference: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript