# How to add JS or CSS files to the end of the queue from the controller action in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have read a lot of topics about this (list at the end of the post) but I can't make my code to work. First I am using old **Zend Framework 1.11**. I have the following layout (just an example):

```
<?php
    $this->headScript('file','/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js');
    $this->headScript('file','/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js');
    // more CSS & JS files goes here
    // some PHP code  goes here
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
           echo $this->headLink();
           echo $this->headStyle();
           echo $this->headScript();
           echo $this->headInline();
        ?> 
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

And this is the function at my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jsgrid.js', 'text/javascript');
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin_console');
}
```

The code at `jsgrid.js` depends on jQuery to be loaded. I want to load the file from the controller as the last one so the result would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsgrid.js"></script>
```

But from the  code above I am getting this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Which is causing the script to fail. How I can achieve this? Any advice?

List of topics:

- [ZendFramework - How to add ->HeadScript() from Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019810/zendframework-how-to-add-headscript-from-controllers)
- [Zend 1.12: Append javascript to bottom of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842010/zend-1-12-append-javascript-to-bottom-of-view)
- [the best way to include js file in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100197/the-best-way-to-include-js-file-in-zend-framework)
- https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html
- http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/24/zend-framework-inject-javascript-code-in-a-actionview/
- and .... a lot more

Answer (score 0):

After several tries finally I have found the solution:

```
$this->view->inlineScript()->appendFile('/js/jsgrid.js', 'text/javascript');
```