# zend framework 3 append script from controller

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-controller

Is it still possible to dynamically append script/files depending on the context?

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269556/how-to-add-js-or-css-files-to-the-end-of-the-queue-from-the-controller-action-in) it was possible in ZF1 but that doesn't work in ZF3.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you need to inject the 'Head Script' view helper into the controller:

```
// controller factory
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    // get service manager
    $serviceLocator = $container->getServiceLocator();

    // get view helper manager
    $viewHelperManager = $sm->get('ViewHelperManager');

    // get 'head script' plugin
    $headScript = $viewHelperManager->get('headScript');

    return new SomeController($headScript);
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function __construct($headScript)
{
    $this->headScript = $headScript;
}

public function someAction()
{
    // append file, etc.
    $this->headScript->appendFile('some-js');
    //...
}
```

But the fact that this plugin is provided as a view helper suggests that they were expecting you to do this in the view, not in the controller. In that case it's much simpler:

```
// in views/some/view.phtml
// no injection needed
$this->headScript()->appendFile('some-js');
```

If possible it would be cleaner to refactor your code so that you are injecting any variables you need to test as conditions for adding the js into the view model.

Comment: Yes I ust figured out how to do it using `$container->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer')->HeadScript()` but your solution is better. The only thing it seems that `getServiceLocator` is deprecated  in ZF3(I got a deprecated message). It works fine whitout it: `$container->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('headScript')`